# Adding/setting era component of date

Tags: swift, foundation

I use the these function of Foundation's `Calendar` type:

- `date(byAdding:value:to:wrappingComponents:)`
- `date(bySetting:value:of:)`

They work fine, except with the `.era` component.

```
var calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
calendar.locale = Locale(identifier: "en")
calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "GMT")!
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.calendar = calendar
formatter.timeZone = calendar.timeZone
formatter.dateFormat = "G yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz"

let date = formatter.date(from: "AD 2019/01/10 20:43:03.752 GMT")!

if let result = calendar.date(byAdding: .era, value: 1, to: date, wrappingComponents: true) {
  print(formatter.string(from: result))
} else {
  print("no result")
}

if let result = calendar.date(bySetting: .era, value: 0, of: date) {
  print(formatter.string(from: result))
} else {
  print("no result")
}
```

This code gives me this result:

```
AD 2019/01/10 20:43:03.752 GMT
no result
```

Adding an era simply returns the same date, even though `wrappingComponents` is set to true, and setting the era produces no result.

I checked the documentation for these methods, but they did not say that this is the case or why.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you change `AD` to `BC` in your date string, the call to `date(bySetting:value:of:)` returns the original date instead of "no result". Odd that you can't change the era.

Comment: You're right. Same when I change the value to 1. I guess, it returns the same date if you set it to the era that it's already set to, and no result if it's a different one.

Comment: And yet, `calendar.maximumRange(of: .era)` returns `Range(0..<2)`, so in theory, adding shouldn't work, but setting to 0 yes, if I understood correctly.

Comment: After some more testing, it seems that setting works if new era >= old era. As for adding, I would have expected it to always work if I set `wrappingComponents` to `true`. It's all very confusing to me.

Comment: What do you think it should mean to add an era? The Gregorian calendar only has two eras (BC and AD) and each one has an infinite duration.

Comment: Same as for the other components. You just count up the available values and if `wrappingComponents` is `true` you start at the first value again, otherwise you increase the next higher level component. There is the special case where you have `wrappingComponents` off and you have exceeded the available eras. In that case I would expect nothing to happen. But in all other cases it should work as for the other components.